# Replace indicator values with actual values

Tags: python-3.x, numpy

I have a numpy array like this

```
array([[0, 0, 1],
       [1, 0, 0],
       [0, 1, 0],
       [0, 0, 1]])
```

and an array with values

```
array([1, 2, 3, 4])
```

I would like to replace the ones in the first two-dimensional array with the corresponding values in the second array. Each row of the first array has exactly one 1, and there is only 1 replacement in the second array.

Result:

```
array([[0, 0, 1],
       [2, 0, 0],
       [0, 3, 0],
       [0, 0, 4]])
```

I would like an elegant solution to achieve this, without loops and such.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's say `a` is the 2D data array and `b` the second 1D array.

An elegant solution would be -

```
a[a==1] = b
```

For performance, leveraging the fact that there's exactly one `1` per row, we could also use `indexing` -

```
a[np.arange(len(a)),a.argmax(1)] = b
```

---

**Selectively assign per row**

If we want to selectively mask and asign values per row, we could use one more level of masking. So, let's say we have the rows to be selected as -

```
select_rows = np.array([1,3])
```

Then, we could do -

```
rowmask = np.isin(np.arange(len(a)),select_rows)
```

So, for the replacement for the first approach would be -

```
a[(a==1) & rowmask[:,None]] = b[rowmask]
```

And for the second one -

```
a[np.arange(len(a))[rowmask],a.argmax(1)[rowmask]] = b[rowmask]
```

Comment: Can I make this work if I have to subset the array further, before assigning the new values? I would need to do something like `a[some other condition][a==1]=b`, where some other condition filters certain rows first?

Comment: @user2974951 Nope, won't work with another condition with that chained indexing. You can store the indices off `some other condition` and then work with those? Is `some other condition` a mask of same shape as `a`?

Comment: I was trying to avoid storing the subsetted array in a new temporary variable. `some other condition` will select a subset of the rows, say row 1, 2 an 5, number of columns is the same.